# How are these terms algebraically equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

This is from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture10-filled.pdf slide 25.

This is the definition of a is congruent to b modulo m. (from slide 24)

[image]

This is an example on the next slide, slide 25
[image]

I know that [image] 
is saying 17 divides A - (-1) or 17 divides A + 1, meaning

A + 1 = 17x where x is some integer, solving for A, you get

A = 17x - 1.

Where does 17x + 16 come from? Algebraically, that is not equal to 17x - 1.

Comment: -1 = 16 mod 17.

Comment: This is bad notation. A better way to write it would be to use $n$ and $(n-1)$ (or $m$) instead of the same variable on both sides of the equation. So think of it as $A=17n-1=17(n-1)+16$ or $A=17n-1=17m+16$ where $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @M.B. I thought r >= 0, r meaning remainder?

Comment: @FengyangWang All you know at this point is that A = 17x - 1 where x is some integer. How do you introduce a 16?

Comment: Make the substitution $m=n-1 \implies n=m+1$ and expand.

Comment: @FengyangWang in my case, x = n - 1?

Comment: Notice that $17x+16=17x+(17-1)=17(x+1)-1$. While $17x+16$ is not algebraically equal to $17x-1$, they are both congruent to each other (mod $17$). In other words, both expressions represent one fewer than a multiple of $17$ (or alternatively, $16$ more than a multiple of $17$).

Comment: @JohnJoy  so 17x - 1 $\equiv 17x + 16 (mod 17). Wait does anyone know why that MathJax code didn't work?

Comment: exactly. $ 17x - 1 \equiv 17x + 16 (\mod 17) $. Do you see why now?

Comment: @JohnJoy Do you know why my MathJax does isn't working?

Comment: try delimiting formulas or expressions with dollar signs

Comment: @JohnJoy Like label it with a dollar sign? I tried that too...

Comment: @FengyangWang so m has to be n - 1? Not just some natural number?

Comment: @JohnJoy So the main point here is that A $\equiv$ 1 mod (17) is the same as A $\equiv$ -1 mod (17)?

Comment: @committedandroider Not exactly. $A\equiv -1\mod 17\equiv 16\mod 17$.